# Yodlee FastLink API

Tags: yodlee

We are building an iOS app that uses Yodlee API's to retrieve credit card transactions for our users.

Right now, we are using FastLink API to connect.

Once accounts are added to a users profile, is there a way to filter the transactions for a specific account by credit card? (For credit card accounts that have multiple cards associated with them)

For example: I have one credit card account with 4 cards associated with it. I am trying to retrieve only the information for a single card.   Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get a particular credit card account by calling Get Account Details API-https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/accounts/getAccountDetails

by passing the accountId and container as creditCard.

Hope this helps.